# bad display in linux terminal

Tags: linux

When I remotely log into one linux terminal, the terminal repeats what I type automatically, which makes the screen a big mess. I can recover the screen by typing ctrl+L. Does anyone know what's the cause and what's the solution?

I'm using mac terminal and ssh.

PS1=[\e]0;\u@\h: \w\a]${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}[\033[01;32m]\u@\h[\033[00m]:[\033[01;34m]\w[\033[00m]\$

Thanks,

Comment: Which terminal - an Xterm window?

Comment: A number of people have voted to close this question as off-topic - can anyone suggest a better forum for it?

Comment: Which protocol? Telnet or SSH? Which client? Which OS on client and server?

Comment: @Mark Bannister: superuser.com maybe?

Comment: I'm assuming you're using Bash, can you provide us the value of the variable `PS1`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit your remote `~/.bashrc` (or whatever) to change the value of the variable `PS1` to something simpler like:

```
PS1='\u@\h:\w\$ '
```

and try again. If it works there must be some mess with the control characters in your `PS1`.

Comment: If you want the color version try something like: PS1='\\[\e[01;32m\\]\u@\h\\[\e[00m\\]:\\[\e[01;34m\\]\w\\[\e[00m\\]\$ '. It should be similar to the one in your answer, but correct.